# Rtabmap transform error with kinect

Tags: navigation, kinect, ros-kinetic, freenect, libfreenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I want to use rtabmap in order to map my environment.
I am using Freenect to extract the data from the kinect using `roslaunch freenect_launch freenect-registered-xyzrgb.launch`
Then i want to run `roslaunch rtabmap_ros kinectlaser.launch` where kinectlaser consists of the following link : [kinectlaser.launch](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_Odometry_.2B-_Fake_2D_laser_from_Kinect)

Unfortunately I am encountering an TF error which says

> [ WARN] [1477558055.097346892]: rtabmap: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_rgb_optical_frame after 0.200000 seconds (for stamp=1477558054.541588)!

> [ERROR] [1477558055.097900220]: TF of received depth image 0 at time 1477558054.541588s is not set, aborting rtabmap update.

> [ WARN] [1477558056.855120061]: rtabmap: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_rgb_optical_frame after 0.200000 seconds (for stamp=1477558056.609746)!

> [ERROR] [1477558056.855669588]: TF of received depth image 0 at time 1477558056.609746s is not set, aborting rtabmap update.

Also when looking into my tf_view I can only see odom, base_footprint, base_link and specific topics for my roomba.

As can be seen in the tf tree this is because camera_rgb_optical_frame is not present in the tf tree
[image description http://i65.tinypic.com/2430t9c.png](http://i65.tinypic.com/2430t9c.png)

This is the same when using freenect.launch and freenect-registered-xyzrgb.launch.
Probably the problem is within the freenect package.
The best way to solve this is to add the following lines to /opt/ros/kinetic/share/freenect_launch/launch/freenect.launch:

```
<node pkg=" tf"  type=" static_transform_publisher" name="depth_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera_depth_frame 100"/>
<node pkg=" tf"  type=" static_transform_publisher" name="rgb_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera_rgb_optical_frame 100"/>
```

To see what the numbers mean please visit this link [static-transform-publisher](http://answers.ros.org/question/208002/static-transformation-publisher/)
And finally you will also see the /camera_depth_frame and /camera_optical_rgb_frame in the tf tree.

In my image i attached them to the odom to make it easily visible but it is best to connect it to the base_link.
[image description http://i64.tinypic.com/2eduix3.png](http://i64.tinypic.com/2eduix3.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246572/rtabmap-transform-error-with-kinect/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So after adding:
`<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 link1_parent link1 100" />` 
To my launch file it finally works.
Although I am not sure if this is the best solution it is atleast a solution that works.
I did this for the camera_rgb_optical_frame and the camera_depth_frame.

---

Originally posted by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) with karma: 171 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-10-30**:
Yeah it looks to be a TF problem. To help better people answering your question, add your TF tree generated by "$ rosrun tf view_frames" in the question.

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-10-31**:
Strangely enough it now works even without the lines so guess it is fixed? edit: Now I have the same error I will add the screens and try to explain why this is happening